В следующем предложении требуется тире или двоеточия между словами "произрастания" и "Шри-Ланке"?
Чай, собранный и упакованный непосредственно на источнике произрастания (?) Шри-Ланке.

"непосредственно на источнике произрастания" - так по-русски не говорят.

Источник произрастания надо удалить. И есть сомнение насчёт «упаковки». Это дело тонкое. Скорее, говорить можно лишь о таре.

Правильно:
Чай, собранный и упакованный непосредственно на месте произрастания (о. Шри-Ланка).
Это номинативная конструкция.
Предложение:
(1)  Чай собран и упакован непосредственно на месте произрастания (о. Шри-Ланка).
(2) Чай собран и упакован непосредственно на месте произрастания —  о. Шри-Ланка. Приложение  в конце предложения обособляется тире.

Спасибо. Можно ли отставить вариант без о. (остров) и использовать в предложном падеже, как Шри-Ланке? На месте произрастания (где?) - Шри-Ланке. Без острова.

По грамматике и пунктуаии можно, а по стилю нежелательно (мое мнение). Здесь стиль информационный, а при склонении Шри-Ланка он блие к  художественной публицистике.  Да и одинокое слово в качестве присоединительного члена (обособление тире) при распространенной первой части не смотрится, графика некрасивая. Так что авторский выбор за вами.
